# Jquery matchMedia max-width not working

Tags: jquery, css

I've got a script that when max-width of 479px's is reached the height and width of drawn lines decreases. But, I can't get it to work properly. Right now, the script doesn't even run. Here is the script. The function I added was `if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 479px)').matches)`

```
    $(window).load(function() {

        if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 479px)').matches)
{


  setTimeout(function() {
    TweenLite.defaultEase = Linear.easeNone;

    //show the square only once js has run
    //visibility set to hidden in css panel
    TweenLite.set(".square", {
        visibility: "visible"
    });

    var tl = new TimelineLite();
    tl.fromTo(".l1", 2, {
            height: 0
        }, {
            height: 22
        })
        .fromTo(".l2", 3, {
            width: 0,

        }, {
            width:44

        })
        .fromTo(".l3", 2, {
            height: 0
        }, {
            height: 22
        })
        .fromTo(".l4", 3, {
            width: 0
        }, {
            width: 44
        })


    tl.timeScale(4) //play faster
 }, 600);
 });


} else {


setTimeout(function() {
    TweenLite.defaultEase = Linear.easeNone;

    //show the square only once js has run
    //visibility set to hidden in css panel
    TweenLite.set(".square", {
        visibility: "visible"
    });

    var tl = new TimelineLite();
    tl.fromTo(".l1", 2, {
            height: 0
        }, {
            height: 227
        })
        .fromTo(".l2", 3, {
            width: 0,

        }, {
            width:445

        })
        .fromTo(".l3", 2, {
            height: 0
        }, {
            height: 227
        })
        .fromTo(".l4", 3, {
            width: 0
        }, {
            width: 445
        })


    tl.timeScale(4) //play faster
}, 600);
});
```

Comment: Where is `window.matchMedia` defined?

Comment: Shouldn't the first part the script run rather than the stuff after `else` when `window.matchMedia`?

Comment: Should it be written like this? https://jsfiddle.net/mrncfjbk/